# Read the xls file in CodeIgniter php and upload into MySQL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with php CodeIgniter, I am not able to read xls file and upload in to database. Plz help me give the MVC for this code I attached the link

[CodeIgniter with PHPExcel fatal error cannot redeclare class IOFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645957/codeigniter-with-phpexcel-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-iofactory)

Comment: i cannot able to find the controller part and view part please help me

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to necessarily use PHPExcel. In one of my projects I used XML Spreadsheets format to import data from excel files. This is easy, you just need to export from MS Excel to a format like `XML Spreadsheet 2003` and then read it in PHP with any kind if XML reader like [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php).

This is a simple reading:

```
$dom = 0;
$sheet_fields = 0;

function open($file_name, $row_tag = "Row", $cell_tag = "Cell", $data_tag = "Data")
    {
      $dom = DOMDocument::load($file_name);

      $rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName($row_tag);

      $counter = 0;

      foreach($rows as $row)
      {
        $counter++;

        $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName($cell_tag);
        $cells_array = array();

        foreach($cells as $cell)
        {
          if($data_tag != "")
          {
            $data = $cell->getElementsByTagName($data_tag);

            foreach($data as $value) $cells_array[] = $value->nodeValue;
          }
          else
          {
            $cells_array[] = $cell->nodeValue;
          }
        }

        $sheet_fields[] = array(
          'ROW' => $counter,
          'CELLS' => $cells_array
        );
      }
    }
```

The best thing is that every newer version of MS Excel does support this format and also sometimes you may need to store your data into Excel format, you can save it as XML file in Excel template and then read it from MS Excel (You could use one of MS Excel exported `XML Spreadsheet 2003` files to see the template).

I hope this would help.

Comment: Of course you can export to another format but he is asking how to read XLS format (that does not come in XML format), so your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @AriWais This solution/workaround is not entirely useless if he could export them to an xml file. Of course there should be tools now to do this since it has passed 5 years from this answer.

Comment: if I ask you how to eat a banana and you answer you could eat an apple, you are not answering my question... I need to import xls, so importing an xlsx or another format its not a valid answer...

Comment: @AriWais This is defiantly not a banana/apple substitution situation. You could still eat your banana, but in a different way :)

Comment: your client has a requirment: Import an xls that comes from another system. You tell him "everytime you want to import that xls, you need to open Excel, open the file, expot to xlsx (for example) and close excel, then import to my system"... that's what you are saying?

Comment: @AriWais No. This is a workaround that works when the criteria meets the situation. Defiantly if this is a customer asking you to do this you have to either do it or don't do it at all, but if this is a situation that you have control on the data you have, you can use this workaround.